# Change value in combobox2 depending on value of combobox1. Javascript, C#

Tags: javascript, c#, sql, reactjs, combobox

I have a SQL database with two tables that have a 1-M relationship. `Table_1` have citynames and `Table_2` have areas within said cities. They are related as such; `Table_1` have a row with 'City1' with an Id=1. `Table_2` have multiple rows with the same AreaId(depending on the area): 'City1_area1', 'City1_area2, 'City2_area5' and so on.

I have a site that takes the data from `Table_1` to a combobox called "City" and another combobox that takes the data from `Table_2` called "Area".

My problem is that I don't know how to make combobox "Area" to only show the relevant data depending on what has been selected on combobox "City".

Please let me know if you need some more information. Thank you.

*Edit: I would also appreciate if you could direct me to some relevant material where I can learn more.*

Comment: so you want to choose in the first combobox a city and the second shall display all the areas from that city? Have you tried to program the part where you get the values from table 2 depending on the chosen city? if so, please post this code

Comment: Exactly. No I don't have that code, sorry.

Comment: So what exactly do you want to know? Do you know how to get the values from table 2 with the name of a city?

Comment: I misread your first question, I know how to put data from Table_1 to combobox 1 and data from Table_2 to combobox 2. But I don't know how to make combobox 2 ONLY show relevant values depending on the selected value in combobox 1. So for example if I choose "Fruit" in combobox1 I only want to see "Apple, Orange, Pineapple" in combobox2 but if I choose "Colours" from combobox1 I ONLY want to see "Red, Blue, Green" in combobox2, not "Apple, Orange, Pineapple".

Comment: I get that point. The important part here is the code that extracts the data from the database. How do you do it? How do you get all `Areas` from `NewYork` for example?